# Unable to save file above web root?

Tags: php, save

I am trying to save a user uploaded file below web root, to prevent it from being retrieved without permission or direct linked to.

The upload works perfectly when saving to a folder which is below web root.

For instance, the page is served from `D:\xampp\htdocs\foo\`, and the script runs at `D:\xampp\htdocs\foo\library\`. When I save to `../../uploads/` the page resolves to `http://my.local/uploads/image.jpg`.

When I save to `$_SERVER['document_root'] . '../uploads/'`, however, the upload fails and no file is located at `D:\xamp\htdocs\uploads`, although I have verified that the path is resolving to the correct location in the script, and that the folders exist and have read/write/execute.

My local dev environment is windows based, but my production server will be a linux server.

Comment: You have to post **PHP error message**. Otherwise it would be empty talk.

Comment: Dunno if it's just a typo but there is no such paths like `.../`

Comment: Did you setup your development server as a _development server_? If so, PHP should be spitting out error messages, post them along with your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent news, Apache is saving you from a world of grief and pain!

Imagine if I renamed `reallybad.exe`  to `svchost.exe` and uploaded it to  `C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe`

You can achieve this by putting a symbolic link from a folder in your web directory to your desired directory.

Comment: Doing some reading on symbolic links and it appears to be a much better solution to the problem, though it will require quite a bit of reworking... which is great, because I'm mostly after learning, not expediency. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are tons of typos in your code.

- `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` not `$_SERVER['document_root']`
- `../uploads/` not `.../uploads/`
- who knows what else

There are some rules to follow.

- always have your `error reporting` at E_ALL
- always have `display_errors` on on the development server
- always pay attention to every error message you see.

and you'll be able yo solve most of the problems yourself

however, if you still can't - there are some other rules

- **ALWAYS post the exact real code,** not some stub you wrote in hurry. It just makes no sense to ask people to find an error not in the code you running! You're just wasting other people's time.
- Always post the **error message.** Programming is an exact science. To solve a problem, a programmer have to **read** the **meaning** of the error message and take **sensible** action. Not guessing of the reasons and take random actions.

Comment: All good advice, but I did report all the info I had. The mistake turned out to be in the writing of the code sample I was using as the basis for this. It uses a different variable then it reported as for where to save.

Answer (score 0):

you say `When I save to $_SERVER['document_root'] . '.../uploads/',`
but I notice several things in there 
1. you have three dots before /uploads  and that won't resolve properly
2. you are using a mixture of windows ....\ notation and linux notation ../../ which might confuse xamp
3. if `$_SERVER['document_root'] is D:\xamp\htdocs\` 
then  `$_SERVER['document_root'] . '..\uploads\' is D:\xamp\uploads`
not `D:\xamp\htdocs\uploads`

since you don't say exactly what `$_SERVER['document_root']` refers to I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

So, in actuality, the upload script that I found on the web had is not using the a variable which it purports to be using, which is why I received no error error message. Turns out the files were being saved, just to a different directory. I had to tweak the code in a few places but it runs now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A better solution might be to store it in a folder, withint your web root, that doesn't have world read permissions. This would prevent access in much the same way as you require.